# NASM assembly code working before, but not now and is dropping a segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, nasm

[edit: I added an image of the error shown in gdb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6owh4.png)
I am having a problem with my assembly code. This code once worked for me and it gave out the right outputs that I need (mainly string1 as I need to change its vowel characters to some other character). A few hours later, however, it stopped working and is now dumping a segmentation fault.

```
section .data
    NULL equ 0
    SYS_EXIT equ 60
    string1 db 'hello everyone', NULL
    strlen dq 0

section .bss
    string2 resb 20

section .text
_start:
    mov rdi, string1
    mov rsi, strlen
    call get_strlen

    mov rdi, qword[strlen]
    mov rsi, string1
    mov rdx, string2
    call get_vowel

exit_here:
    mov rax, SYS_EXIT
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall


get_strlen:
    len_loop:
        mov al, byte[rdi]
        cmp al, NULL
        je return

        inc rdi
        inc byte[rsi]
        jmp len_loop
    return:
        ret

get_vowel:
    mov rcx, rdi
    mov rsi, rsi
    mov rdi, rdx
    cld
    str_loop:

    lodsb
    stosb

    cmp al, 'a'
    je vowel_a
    cmp al, 'e'
    je vowel_e
    cmp al, 'i'
    je vowel_i
    cmp al, 'o'
    je vowel_o
    cmp al, 'u'
    je vowel_u
    loop str_loop

    mov byte[rdi], NULL
    jmp str_copy

    vowel_a:
        dec rdi
        mov byte[rdi], '@'
        inc rdi
        jmp str_loop

    vowel_e:
        dec rdi
        mov byte[rdi], '3'
        inc rdi
        jmp str_loop

    vowel_i:
        dec rdi
        mov byte[rdi], '1'
        inc rdi
        jmp str_loop

    vowel_o:
        dec rdi
        mov byte[rdi], '0'
        inc rdi
        jmp str_loop

    vowel_u:
        dec rdi
        mov byte[rdi], 'U'
        inc rdi
        jmp str_loop

    str_copy:
        mov rcx, rdi
        mov rsi, rdx
        mov rdi, rsi
        cld
        jmp loop1

        loop1:
           lodsb
           stosb
           loop loop1 
           mov byte[rdi], NULL
           jmp return1
    return1:
     ret
```

according to gdb, there is a problem with on loop1 at the function get_vowel. However, with what I currently know about assembly, I am fairly sure about that it works.

The supposed value of string1 in this case is

```
h3ll0 3v3ry0n3
```

however it only outputs its default value

Comment: To add to this, before all of this happened, my pc suddenly became wonky and really slow so I restarted it and it came with an error code as well that is supposedly related with my ram. Not sure this has something to do with it but I could might as well put it out there.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue probably, but you forgot to put `global _start` before defining `_start` so the linker can't find it and may default to some other address for entry.

Comment: yeah i omitted the parts that make the functions global in the post

Comment: It would help to include the segfault info, exact line number, and perhaps the register values.  Those register values are probably the key to finding what went wrong.  Also, having all labels start in column 0 makes it easier to read :)

Comment: After `loop str_loop` `rcx` is zero. Then you do a `jmp str_copy` which eventually ends up at `loop loop1` which then tries to repeat 2^64 times. That is one possible failure mode, there might be others. Use single step in gdb.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Hi, I added an image of the gdb results I got

Comment: @Jester I think this might be it because the value of rcx is an address. Im not sure though because it worked a while ago

Comment: Yeah. You have `jmp str_copy` but `str_copy` starts with `mov rcx, rdi` but `rdi` is already set to an address by `mov rdi, rdx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the code wasnt really working in the first place lol. The value of `rcx` in the loop in `str_copy` is an address and the values of `rdi` and `rsi` are not getting switched so if anything, nothing right is happening in that part of the code. To solve this, I initialized another register with the same value of `rcx` and another function that swaps the address of `rdi` and `rsi` so I can copy the contents of `string2` to `string1` as shown by the function below

```
swap:
push rbp
mov rbp, rsp
sub rsp, 8

mov r10, rdi
mov qword[rbp-8], r10
mov r10, rsi
mov rdi, r10
mov r10, qword[rbp-8]
mov rsi, r10
jmp swap1

swap1:
mov rcx, rdx
mov rsi, rsi
mov rdi, rdi
cld

loop1:
    movsb
    loop loop1
    mov byte[rdi], NULL

add rsp, 8
pop rbp
ret
```